# handle two asynchronous process with promises

Tags: node.js, q

I am implementing pagination in mysql.
Pagination cannot be done using one query alone.
It consists of the select step and the count step which counts all records.
The usual way to do this is to do select then in the success callback, we do the counting.
Counting happen after selecting when in fact they can or should be happening simultaneously.
My question is how do I use promises to make those two processes run simultaneously and then return only if the two processes are both finished?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check https://github.com/kriskowal/q, i think if you have multiple promises to resolve then you can use "all" method of Q

example  :

```
Q.all([
fooPromise1(),
fooPromise2()
]);
```